# Windows MSI Installer via Wix 2 : Can 'OnlyDetect' be dynamic, allowing optional upgrade?

Tags: wix

My company uses Wix 2.0 in the build chain.

When our users try to install a later build over an older one, the old build is replaced IF the major version number is the same. Otherwise, we let them have a side-by-side install so they can evaluate the new version before buying (no charge for minor version number updates).

However, I'd like to offer the user the choice of replacing any previous version.

From what I know of Wix, this would mean making the OnlyDetect attribute of the UpgradeVersion element dynamic somehow.

Is this possible without a custom action that hacks the table? The msi will be launched from a .exe gui so I can set properties and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use OnlyDetect. You author the Upgrade element (or use the helper MajorUpgrade element if using WiX v3.5+) to do the upgrade and then condition the RemoveExistingProducts action. No hackery necessary.